# Find the first derivative of $\int \limits_{0}^{h(x)}f(x,t) dt$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

Find the first derivative of this integral:

$\int\limits_{0}^{h(x)}f(x,t)dt$

Comment: What have you tried?  Leibniz rule for integrals?  Rewriting through FTOC and using multivariable chain rule?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I have no idea what to try when I asked the question. I'll give Leibniz rule a go and see whether I get anywhere. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Switch from one variable to two variables"

Consider :

$$\phi:(x,y)\mapsto\int_0^yf(x,t)\,dt$$

We know, by FTOC and Leibniz formula that :

$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}(x,y)=\int_0^y\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,t)\,dt\qquad\mathrm{and}\qquad\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}(x,y)=f(x,y)$$

Now, observe that :

$$\int_0^{h(x)}f(x,t)\,dt=\phi(x,h(x))$$

Hence :

$$\frac d{dx}\left(\int_0^{h(x)}f(x,t)\,dt\right)=\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}(x,h(x))+\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}(x,h(x))\,h'(x)$$

that is :

> $$\frac d{dx}\left(\int_0^{h(x)}f(x,t)\,dt\right)=\int_0^{h(x)}f(x,t)\,dt+f(x,h(x))\,h'(x)$$